# Eliminar nodo de una lista doblemente enlazada en C

Tags: c

tengo un problema al eliminar un nodo de una lista doblemente enlazada en c. Implemente una función para esto y además dicha función tiene que retornar el dato eliminado. El código se encuentra a continuación:

```
void * popCurrent(DoublyLinkedList * list) 
{  
    void *data;
    Node *aux;
    data = calloc(1, sizeof(void *));

    if ( data == NULL ) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    // Verificar si la lista está vacía
    if ( !(list -> head && list -> head -> data) )
        return NULL;
    else
    {
        data = list -> current -> data;
        aux = list -> current;
    }
    // Verificar si el current se encuentra en head    
    if ( list -> current == list -> head )
        list -> head = list -> current -> next;
    // Verificar si el current se encuentra en la cola de la lista    
    if ( list -> current -> next != NULL )
        list -> current -> next -> prev = list -> current -> prev;
    // Verificar si el current no de encuentra en head    
    if ( list -> current -> prev != NULL )
        list -> current -> prev -> next = list -> current -> next;

    free(aux);
    return data;
}
```

Al momento de compilar, me elimina todos los nodos a partir del current(puntero actual(nodo) de la lista).

```
LISTA ORIGINAL
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 

RESULTADO ESPERADO:
Dato del nodo eliminado: 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

RESULTADO FINAL:
Dato del nodo eliminado: 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Por se acaso estas son las estructuras que utilicé:

```
typedef struct Node Node;

typedef struct DoublyLinkedList DoublyLinkedList;

struct Node {
    void * data; // Puntero al dato
    Node * next; // Puntero al siguiente Node
    Node * prev; // Puntero al Node previo
};

struct DoublyLinkedList {
    Node * head; // Puntero al primer elemento
    Node * tail; // Puntero al ultimo elemento
    Node * current; // Puntero para poder recorrer la lista
};
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar a resolver esta duda se lo agradecería. Saludos

Comment: Si con list -> current -> next  estás accediendo al siguiente nodo, con list -> current -> next -> prev = list -> current -> prev estarías sobrescribiendo el nodo actual en vez de actualizar la variable del siguiente. No uso C pero me da la impresión de que anda por ahí el problema.

Answer (score 3):

Para eliminar un nodo de una lista doblemente enlazada, solo debes obtener el nodo anterior y el siguiente al que quieres eliminar, no he visto tu implementación original, pero te puedes guiar con este fragmento de código:

```
void *popCurrent(DoublyLinkedList *list) {
  // Verificamos si la lista está vacía
  if (!(list && list->head && list->current))
    return NULL;

  Node *curr = list->current;  // Nodo "actual", el que será eliminado.
  Node *last = curr->prev;     // Nodo anterior al actual.
  Node *next = curr->next;     // Nodo siguiente al actual.
  void *data = curr->data;

  // Verificamos que el actual sea la cabeza (aka head):
  if (list->current == list->head) {
    list->current = next;
    list->head = next;          // Recuerda asignar la nueva cabeza y el nuevo nodo "actual"
    list->current->prev = NULL; // Recuerda eliminar la cabeza anterior.
  }
  // Si no es la cabeza, entonces o es la cola, o es algo del medio.
  else {
    list->current = next;
    if (next) // Sin esto, "next" puede ser NULL (cola) y causar segfault.
      next->prev = last;  
  }
  free(curr); // Luego de aislar este nodo, podemos eliminarlo.
  return data;
}
```

Básicamente, cada vez que vas a eliminar un nodo de una lista doblemente enlazada, debes ajustar el nodo anterior para que su "siguiente" nodo sea el siguiente del nodo actual, pasa igual con el anterior del nodo siguiente, debes hacer que apunte hacia el anterior, algo como esta imagen, por si no se entiende lo que quiero decir (Ignora mis asombrosos poderes de excel):

[image: Super poderes para dibujar]

Nota: Al hacer `calloc` estás colocando memoria dinámica para la variable `data`, luego sobreescribes `data` perdiendo los bytes que colocaste, si quieres sacar la data, solo necesitas asignar el valor una vez como aparece en el código que te puse más arriba.

Saludos!